# CSS hover isn't working for my divs

Tags: html, css, hover

I can't get the hover CSS effect to work on my divs.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!doctype html><!--HTML5-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="chaosMain.css"/> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="featuredContent1"></div>   
</body> 
</html>
```

Here is the CSS for it:

```
    html{
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        height:100%;
        width:100%
    }
    body{
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px; 
        height:100%;     
        width:100%;
        background-color:#F0F0F0;
        color:#F0F0F0;
    }
    div{
        position:fixed; 
    }

    #featuredContent1{
        margin-left:8.5%;
        margin-top:11.7%;
        width:23%;
        height:40%;
        background-color:#F26E24;
        z-index:-1;       
        border-radius:2px;
    }
    #featuredContent1:hover {
        width:25%;
        height:42%;
    }
```

I can't find what is wrong with it, but the hover has no effect whatsoever.

Comment: see demonstration in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this line from #featuredContent1 style

```
z-index:-1;
```

code

```css
 html{
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        height:100%;
        width:100%
    }
    body{
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px; 
        height:100%;     
        width:100%;
        background-color:#F0F0F0;
        color:#F0F0F0;
    }
    div{
        position:fixed; 
    }

    #featuredContent1{
        margin-left:8.5%;
        margin-top:11.7%;
        width:23%;
        height:40%;
        background-color:#F26E24;
            
        border-radius:2px;
    }
    #featuredContent1:hover {
        width:25%;
        height:42%;
    background:red;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="featuredContent1"></div>   
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown in A B's answer, this is caused by the negative `z-index`. The div is technically *hidden behind the body*, so the mouse is never really hovering on the div.

Viewed from the "side" it would look like this:

```
------------------ (top)
------------------ body
------------------ element
```

So, your mouse is always hovering the body, but never hovering the element.